# SQLAlchemy Conditional Relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to have a one to many relation between two ORM objects and extend this with a second relation that links to the same 'many' object while applying a constraint.

The following example may elaborate:

```
class Users(SQLABase):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    addresses = relationship('Addresses', backref='user')


class Addresses(SQLABase):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    historic = (String(1))
    add1 = Column(String)
    user = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

I would like an attribute 'Users.valid_addresses' that relates to the same 'addresses' table filtering where Addresses.historic == 'N' like the following query:

```
Session.Query(Addresses).filter_by(historic = 'N').all()
```

I'm looking for the "SQLAlchemy way".

- Can I apply a condition to a relation?
- Am I expected to iterate over the results of the current relation?
- Should I create an additional 'valid_addresses' object based on an SQL
  view of the addresses table applying the condition?

I have the feeling this has already been answered but I'm failing to phrase the question correctly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is covered in the SQLAlchemy docs under "[Specifying Alternate Join Conditions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions)".

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    boston_addresses = relationship("Address",
                    primaryjoin="and_(User.id==Address.user_id, "
                        "Address.city=='Boston')")

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))

    street = Column(String)
    city = Column(String)
    state = Column(String)
    zip = Column(String)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Was thinking in terms of filters rather than joins.